# Chain complex homotopy equivalent to its homology

Tags: homology-cohomology, homological-algebra

Let $(C_*,d)$ be a chain complex of vector spaces over a field $F$.  Can always be constructed a homotopy equivalence $C_* \rightarrow H(C_*)$ ? (Here $H(C_*)$ is seen as a chain complex with $d=0$)

There is a split  exact sequence $0 \rightarrow B_* \rightarrow Z_* \rightarrow  H_*(C) \rightarrow 0$ so we have a map $H_*(C) \rightarrow Z_* \subseteq C_*$ which induces a quasi-isomorphism. Is this map the homotopy equivalence between $C_*$ and its homology?

Comment: Presumably, where $H_*(C)$ has a zero $d$ as a chain complex?

Comment: Yes $H(C_*)$ carries the zero differential. I will point it out explicitly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of a field, this is true. We can write $Z = B\oplus i(H)$ for $i : H\to Z$ a section of the projection and $C = L\oplus B\oplus i(H)$. Define $j : H\to C$ using $i$, and define $q : C\to H$ by sending $L$ and $B$ to $0$, and projecting $i(H)$ back.

These are maps of complexes: $qd = 0 = dq$ since $H(C)$ has trivial differential, and $jd=dj=0$ since $j$ lands on cycles. Moreover, by construction, $qi = 1$.

Finally define $h : C\to C$ by picking a section $s : B\to C$ of $d : C\to B$ and sending
$b\in B$ to $s(b)$, and $L$ and $i(H)$ to $0$. Then,

1. If $l\in L$, then $(hd+dh)l = l = l-iql = (1-iq)(l)$,
2. If $b\in B$, then $(hd+dh)b = dsb = b = (1-iq)(b)$,
3. If $z\in i(H)$, then $(hd+dh)z = 0 = (1-iq)(z)$,

so $dh+hd = 1 - qi$ is a homotopy between $1$ and $iq$.